# Using express.js to execute a function after receiving an http request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

So I have an angular controller that successfully makes an http request after a button is pressed. I have a node.js server running which gets the request and then sends back `YOU HAVE SUCCEEDED! HTTP REQUEST RECEIVED!`. I want to execute a function when the request is received, but the function lives in a file inside a folder which is in `./Source/Server/test.js`.

How do I tell my server.js file to send the command to run the function???

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Source/Client/Templates'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/Source/Client/Templates/Home.html', {root: __dirname });
});
app.get('/ThisIsATest', function (req, res) {
  res.send('YOU HAVE SUCCEEDED! HTTP REQUEST RECEIVED!')
})
app.listen(3000);
console.log("running at port 3000");
```

test.js:

```
var run = require('./quickstart.js');
run.runQuickstart();
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('DaycareApp').controller('WaitingListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.test = function() {
        $http.get('/ThisIsATest')
        .then(function(response) {
            alert(response.data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to move the contents of `test.js` into the handler, right before you're calling `res.send(...)`.

Comment: @ChrisG

So something along the lines of:

`var runQuickstart = require('./Source/Server/quickstart.js');` 

`app.get('/ThisIsATest', function (req, res, runQuickstart)`

`{runQuickstart.runQuickstart();})`

should do the trick? It says runQuickstart() is not a function but maybe I'm passing the variable in wrong or something....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In test.js you can export your module like this

```
var run = require('./quickstart.js');

function mySpecialFunction() {
    return run.runQuickstart();
}

module.exports = {
    mySpecialFunction: mySpecialFunction
};
```

Now in your server.js or wherever your controller is you can call the function by inluding test.js in your module using require.

```
var test = require('./test.js');

app.get('/ThisIsATest', function (req, res) {
  res.send(test.mySpecialFunction());
});
```

Comment: Was just thinking along these lines, but your answer does a better job of wrapping the original than mine :-)

Comment: @KiwiHaxer Thank you for the help! This worked wonderfully :) Is there also a way to send the message back at the same time..? If I do `res.send('YOU HAVE SUCCEEDED! HTTP REQUEST RECEIVED!' + test.mySpecialFunction());` the alert from the controller gives `"YOU HAVE SUCCEEDED! HTTP REQUEST RECEIVED!undefined"`

Comment: yes just make sure you return a value in the mySpecialFunction. I have updated the answer to show you.

Comment: @KiwiHaxer Thank you! That's awesome! Everything works

Answer (score 2):

You can require **test.js** as a file after exposing the necessary functions, like this:

```
// test.js
// ========
var run = require('./quickstart.js');

module.exports = {
  run: function () {
    run.runQuickstart();
  }
};
```

In **server.js**, require it:

```
var test = require('./Source/Server/test');
```

and use it with: `test.run()`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you do something like:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var run = require('./path/to/quickstart.js');

// ...

app.get('/ThisIsATest', function (req, res) {
  run.runQuickstart();
  res.send('YOU HAVE SUCCEEDED! HTTP REQUEST RECEIVED!')
})

// ...
```

And then in test.js:

```
var run = require('./quickstart.js');

exports.runQuickstart = function() {
  run.runQuickstart();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can require the file

```
var outsideFunction  = require(__dirname + '/Source/Server/test.js');
```

then add it to the route.

```
app.get('/ThisIsATest', function (req, res) {
      outsideFunction(req, res);
      res.send('YOU HAVE SUCCEEDED! HTTP REQUEST RECEIVED!')
})
```

Comment: could I use this to send an object back after running an asynchronous function???? [Here is a reddit post I made regarding the issue I'm currently having and I'm curious to see if your answer to this question may help with that issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/5coezh/httpexpresssqlite3_having_some_issues_responding/)

Comment: If you want to send an object back, you will need to remove the res.send from the app.get and add it inside the outsideFunction. Although the function is asynchronous, the http call can only have 1 return.